# MySQL Query 10 Tables (Sequelize or Raw Query)

Tags: mysql, sql, json, node.js, sequelize.js

In order to return the following JSON example, we need to query 10 tables, while looking up values in between.
My knowledge of SQL is limited, so we are here asking for help.

#### JSON:

```
{
  project: 1,
  name: "BluePrint1",
  description: "BluePrint 1 Description",
  listWorkPackages: [
    {
      id: 1,
      name: "WorkPackage 1 Name",
      description: "WorkPackage 1 Description",
      type: "WorkPackage Type",
      department: "WorkPackage Department",
      status: "Workpackage work status"
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      name: "WorkPackage 2 Name",
      description: "WorkPackage 2 Description",
      type: "WorkPackage Type",
      department: "WorkPackage Department",
      status: "Workpackage work status"
    }
  ],
  assignments: [
    {
      id: 3,
      name: "WorkPackage 3 Name",
      description: "WorkPackage 3 Description",
      type: "WorkPackage Type",
      department: "WorkPackage Department",
      status: "Workpackage work status"
    }
  ]
}
```

#### Database:

The database looks like this (*open in new tab for more details)* :

[image: database diagram]

#### Logic:

With the WorkerID, we want All the **WorkPackages** that:

- Have the same **Type** as the **Worker**;
- And belong to the same **Department**;
- And also the ones by direct **Assignment** (*via table WA_Assignments*)

So we can sent the information present on the JSON, we need to look into these 10 tables:

1. WK_Worker
2. WT_WorkerType
3. TY_Type
4. WP_WorkPackage
5. WE_WorkPackageExecution
6. WS_WorkStatus
7. BL_Blueprint
8. PR_Project
9. DP_Department
10. WA_WorkAssignments

#### My Problem:

My knowledge of SQL is limited to JOIN's:

```
SELECT *
FROM BL_Blueprint 
JOIN PR_Project ON BL_idBlueprint = PR_idBlueprint
JOIN WP_WorkPackage ON BL_idBlueprint = WP_idBlueprint
JOIN WE_WorkPackageExecution ON WE_idWorkPackage = WP_idWorkPackage
JOIN DP_Department ON WE_idDepartment = DP_idDepartment
```

And we need to only search work packages that have the same **Type** as the **Worker**, but we don't know the types before hand, only after looking into the table *WT_WorkerType*.

I read about subQuery where you can SELECT in the WHERE field, but couldn't get my head around it, and get a working query.

#### Problems:

In the end, my problems are:

1. The SQL query;

I am using [Sequelize](https://github.com/sequelize/sequelize), if it can help, but from the docs I think a Raw Query would be easier.

Thank you all for your help and support.

---

#### SOLUTION

All the love goes to @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi (in the comments) that helped me arrive at the solution

The **First** *SELECT* gets the Assignments and the **Second** the logic describe above. The labels help to identify which is which, and we order  to ease the creation of the JSON.

```
SELECT *
FROM
    ((SELECT 
        BL_Name,
            BL_Description,
            WP_Name,
            WP_Description,
            PR_idProject,
            WE_idWorkPackageExecution,
            WE_idWorkStatus,
            TY_TypeName,
            TY_Description,
            WS_WorkStatus,
            DP_Name,
            DP_Description,
            'second_select'
    FROM
        WK_Worker, WP_WorkPackage
    INNER JOIN BL_Blueprint ON BL_idBlueprint = WP_idBlueprint
    INNER JOIN PR_Project ON PR_idBlueprint = BL_idBlueprint
    INNER JOIN WE_WorkPackageExecution ON WE_idWorkPackage = WP_idWorkPackage
        AND WE_idProject = PR_idProject
    INNER JOIN WS_WorkStatus ON WS_idWorkStatus = WE_idWorkStatus
    INNER JOIN DP_Department ON DP_idDepartment = WE_idDepartment
    INNER JOIN WA_WorkAssignments ON WA_idWorkPackageExecution = WE_idWorkPackageExecution
    INNER JOIN TY_Type ON TY_idType = WP_idType
    WHERE
        WA_idWorker = 1 AND WK_idWorker = 1) UNION ALL (SELECT 
        BL_Name,
            BL_Description,
            WP_Name,
            WP_Description,
            PR_idProject,
            WE_idWorkPackageExecution,
            WE_idWorkStatus,
            TY_TypeName,
            TY_Description,
            WS_WorkStatus,
            DP_Name,
            DP_Description,
            'first_select'
    FROM
        WK_Worker, WP_WorkPackage
    JOIN BL_Blueprint ON BL_idBlueprint = WP_idBlueprint
    JOIN PR_Project ON PR_idBlueprint = BL_idBlueprint
    JOIN WE_WorkPackageExecution ON WE_idWorkPackage = WP_idWorkPackage
        AND WE_idProject = PR_idProject
    JOIN WS_WorkStatus ON WS_idWorkStatus = WE_idWorkStatus
    JOIN DP_Department ON DP_idDepartment = WE_idDepartment
    JOIN TY_Type ON TY_idType = WP_idType
    WHERE
        WK_idWorker = 1
            AND DP_idDepartment IN 
            (SELECT 
                WK_idDepartment
            FROM
                WK_Worker
            WHERE
                WK_idWorker = 1)
            AND WP_idType IN 
            (SELECT 
                TY_idType
            FROM
                TY_Type
            JOIN WT_WorkerType ON TY_idType = WT_idType
            WHERE
                WT_idWorker = 1)
    )
) AS T1
ORDER BY T1.PR_idProject
```

Comment: Could you post that not-working WHERE? It'd probably help in understanding the logic you are trying to implement.

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi Of course. From the web I arrived at that. Now I am trying to see if I can get the information from the other tables. I have to be careful with the JOIN's. Am I on a good track?

Comment: Try only joining the tables that you need data from (or that link those tables). We'll work on the WHERE after that :)

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi Sorry, I already have 2 where. I think all the JOIN's are there, should the Assignments be on the Where or as a JOIN?

Comment: Can you post the results from the current query vs. the expected results?

Comment: @MihaiOvidiuDrăgoi, posted the output. I get the correct 2 records, but I want to receive 3 in total, that last one is from the Assignments.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/91467/discussion-between-rui-brito-and-mihai-ovidiu-drgoi).

Comment: I wrote a lot in chat :) are you still around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you seem to need a single resultset that is composed from two different joins, you should probably do something like

```
SELECT * from
(
SELECT 1 
UNION ALL 
SELECT 2 
) a
ORDER by ...
```

Both your select statements should also include the logic name as distinct columns (like 'firstselect') - this way you will know which select your row comes from.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to try to do a subquery with sequelize, you could use a literal in part of your query:

```
User.findAll({
  attributes: [
    [sequelize.literal('SELECT ...'), 'subq'],
  ]
}).then(function(users) {

});
```

Comment: I end up using your response for another case I had. Thanks for the help.